# Deployment failed-Script at specified location: start.sh run as user ec2-user failed with exit code 127

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy code from GitHub to CodeDeploy in AWS Amazon.
I have sample HelloWorld application.I have appspec.yml that looks like this:

```
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/server

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: stop.sh
      timeout: 20
      runas: ec2-user
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: start.sh
      timeout: 20
      runas: ec2-user
  ValidateService:
    - location: validate.sh
      timeout: 120
      runas: ec2-user
```

and buldspec.yml:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean package --quiet
artifacts:
  discard-paths: yes
  files:
    - target/*
    - scripts/*
    - appspec.yml
```

start.sh

```
cd /home/ec2-user/server
sudo /usr/bin/java -jar -Dserver.port=80 \
    *.jar > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

stop.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo killall java
exit 0
```

and validate.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Waiting for 15 seconds before checking health.."
sleep 15

status_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:80)
if [[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]] ; then
  echo "App is not healthy - $status_code"
  exit 1
else
  echo "App is responding with $status_code"
  exit 0
fi
```

My deployment failed and error says:

Script at specified location: start.sh run as user ec2-user failed with exit code 127
Logs
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStart
Script - start.sh
[stderr]/usr/bin/env: bash : No such file or directory

please can someone help me

Comment: I don't see a hashbang like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the beginning of start.sh. Or is that a copy paste mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have mentioned a wrong path for start.sh in appspec.yml. It is trying to look for the script in root path. Since your scripts are in "scripts" folder you have to mention it like below.

```
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/server

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop.sh
      timeout: 20
      runas: ec2-user
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start.sh
      timeout: 20
      runas: ec2-user
  ValidateService:
    - location: scripts/validate.sh
      timeout: 120
      runas: ec2-user
```